# Rails Carrierwave where is it storing my uploaded images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a perfectly working app and I just incorporated image file uploading using [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

The default path set in **picture_uploader.rb** is:

"*uploads/#{ model.class.to_s.underscore} /#{ mounted_as }/#{ model.id }*"

The picture upload fines and a renamed version of the same image is stored in root directory of my app (***RackMultipart20160523-3241-ad9oou.jpg***).

I would like to know the path to where Carrierware uploads the image, help? I have searched everywhere but can't find the folder "***uploads***".

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: try app/public/uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your uploaded images in your application directory as
**`You_application/public/uploads`**

***For reference:***
If you want to change the storage directory, you can do it as following by overriding the `store_dir` method.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    'public/new/upload/directory'
  end
end
```

Comment: I dont have a uploads folder in my public folder. I even made an empty upload folder and tried uploading image but it remains empty

Comment: Ok. It just suddenly appeared there. Possibly I forgot to restart my server after setting up carrierwave.

Answer (score 0):

You will find **uploads** folder in your **application's/public/uploads** folder.

Comment: I dont have a uploads folder in my public folder. I even made an empty upload folder and tried uploading image but it remains empty